# Using Process Substitution in docker as input <(command)

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker, bioinformatics, process-substitution

Recently, I faced some problems in developing bash pipelines with docker.
This regards to the use of process substitution [<()] as input for a specific docker command.
I know that this is a problem of partition mounted.
Does anyone know an alternative way, despite write the file, to work with process substitution in docker?

Command:

```
docker run --rm -v`pwd`:`pwd` docker pull staphb/samtools samtools bedcov <(grep "chr" `pwd`/hsa-genome/BED-new/On-Off_targets.txt | sed -E 's/:|-|;/\t/g' | cut -f2-6) `pwd`/HSA-output/Mapping_files/file.bam

samtools bedcov: can't open BED file '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory
```

Best regards, Willian

Comment: Probably not related to your issue but can you even do a `docker pull` as an argument to `docker run`?  Also I'm not familiar with samtools or bedcov but you unfortunately can't pass process substitution into the container.  The output of your substitution is stored in /dev/fd/63 on your local machine and the container doesn't have that fd

Comment: There is two input for the docker command samtools bedcov, the first one came from <() and the second is the bam file. Don't using dockerization, the command samtools bedcov works well, and using docker directly with a file instead of <() the command also works well. But if there isn't a way to use docker command with <(), I'll write a file to use as input.